# Counting NaN values by row, in a List

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Example data:

```
dictionary = {'col1':[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]],'col2': [[1,'nan',3], 
[1,2,'nan'],[1,2,3]], 'col3': [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,'nan',3]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
```

I have a DataFrame of lists and I want to count the number of NaN values by row:

```
col1     col2       col3   
[1,2,3]  [1,NaN,3]  [1,2,3]   
[1,2,3]  [1,2,NaN]  [1,2,3]   
[1,2,3]  [1,2,3]    [1,NaN,3]
```

I used

```
acceptable_data_df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(lambda x: list(itertools.chain(*x)), axis=1)
```

to convert them to one list and hopefully make it easier but I'm still stuck. (First column was text)

```
[1,2,3,1,NaN,3,1,2,3]   
[1,2,3,1,2,NaN,1,2,3]   
[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,NaN,3]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `stack` + `explode` + `isna` to get a Series where it's True for NaN and False otherwise. Then `groupby` + `sum` fetches the number of NaN values per row:

```
df['number of NaN'] = df.stack().explode().isna().groupby(level=0).sum()
```

Output:

```
        col1         col2         col3  number of NaN
0  [1, 2, 3]  [1, nan, 3]    [1, 2, 3]              1
1  [1, 2, 3]  [1, 2, nan]    [1, 2, 3]              1
2  [1, 2, 3]    [1, 2, 3]  [1, nan, 3]              1
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC use:

```
df['count'] = (df.col1 + df.col2 + df.col3).apply(lambda x: pd.isna(x).sum())
```

Answer (score 1):

A "boring" way to count "NaN" while keeping the values as a string is to just count how many times the `"NaN"` string appears:

```
(df["col1"] + df["col2"] + df["col3"]).str.count("NaN")
```